# Unable to connect to MYSQL server

Tags: mysql

Hi here i am facing a strange situation in which when i try to connect to mysqlserver by executing the command like

```
mysql -uroot -p msp;
Enter password: *******
```

I am getting an error message like

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'msp;'

While I do have a database named **msp** and strange thing is that when i try to take dump of the database **msp** by executing the command like

```
C:\>mysql -uroot -p msp -e "show tables">D:\localtables.txt
Enter password: *******
```

Works fine. What is the actual reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: Try it without the terminating `;`.

Comment: You have a database name **msp**, not **msp;**?

Answer (score 4):

Your database is named `msp`, not `msp;`

Remove the semicolon from the end of the command line.